# Why is half of my Mac's storage full with "system" files?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

What does this mean:

[image: 69.93 GB available of 249.78 GB]

The "system" section is taking up 80 GB. Why is it taking up so much and is there any way I can reduce it?

Comment: Files with unknown extensions fill up the System section, so that would explain that.

Comment: @owlswipe that's a good answer. I didn't know that, maybe the fact that most of my device is filled up with program source files is what the large System section represents?

Comment: Yep, that's what's happened to my MB too.

Comment: In retrospect I am not so sure that this is a duplicate. This question is more wondering what constitutes "system" files and why this section in particular is so large. None of the answers on the "duplicate" address this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure either :). If you need any more help with this let me know!

Comment: @theonlygusti such a question would likely to be 'too broad'. If you can limit its scope, you're welcome to [edit] your question and cast a reopen vote on it; it will automatically enter the reopen review queue and the community will decide whether to reopen it or not.